# How do the Statistics work?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

[image]

Looking at the statistics in my game, I noticed that the Nature one is not growing as the other ones are.
How exactly does it work? I am sharing videos of nature and I've bought plants, but it stays at zero.

What do I have to do to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your Nature is level 5, so I think you just don't have any experience towards level 6. You actually are making progress, even though it doesn't look like it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The bar shows how much experience you have gotten from items. In your case, you just reached Level 5 in Nature, which is why the bar is empty. You'd need to buy more Nature-themed items to increase it further.

Also, you currently get 1200% views from nature videos, but at 350% of the time due to the level and the knowledge upgrades you got both in general and for nature videos.

Answer (score -1):

Once you get to a high enough level, the lower level upgrades might not affect your higher xp level.

Try buying the highest level nature item from the store.

If that doesn't help, it may be worth restarting the game, it could just be a glitch.

Comment: That is not true. Lower level upgrades are needed to access latter upgrade tiers.

Comment: Yes I know they are, but i am assuming that the lower level upgrades would not make a difference or make a significantly lower difference to the xp when you get to a higher level, as the lower level upgrades give you less xp than the higher level ones. Nothing that I have said is false.

Comment: Well, in any case, if you want the follower upgrades, you'll need the others first. And you can only upgrade follower intake per video by them.

Comment: Thank you everybody (: The statistics is about how much you need to reach the next level and you increase the levels buying items acording to the bar as James said.